# Sanitize href on backend to prevent XSS attacks

Tags: go, xss

I have to sanitize potentially vulnerable href values on backend side that will be used to build HTML on FE side. For example such values `javascript:alert('XSS')`, `\t\t\tj\ta\tv\ta\ts\tc\tr\ti\tp\tt:alert('XSS')` should be found and excluded

There are few ways to sanitize HTML itself using `html.EscapeString(href)` or more configurable https://github.com/microcosm-cc/bluemonday but how to clean up href values it is open question for me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to allow URLs, you could use the [`url.Parse()` from `net/url`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#Parse) function to parse the value as an URL and make sure only valid URLs are allowed.